# How to find all rectangular shaped tiles in an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I want to detect and isolate (get sub-images) of all Rummikub tiles in an image. This is the image of Rummikub tiles:

[image: Image of rummikub tiles]

I tried to find the contours of the tiles in an edged image. However, I could not manage to find all the contours of all the tiles.

This is what I got so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('RK1.jpg',3)

# Converting the image to grayscale.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Smoothing without removing edges.
gray_filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 6, 400, 400)

# Applying the canny filter
edges_filtered = cv2.Canny(gray_filtered, 50, 30)

# find contours in the edged image
contours= cv2.findContours(edges_filtered, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

# loop over our contours
for contour in contours:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.015 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then draw contour
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

This is the result:

[Result of rectangle detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5g27.png)

I would very much appreciate suggestions on how to reliably find all the contours of all the tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple method

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Adaptive threshold
- Dilate to form single contours
- Find contours and filter using aspect ratio and contour area
- Extract ROI using Numpy slicing and save ROI

---

Detected objects

[image]

Here's each individually saved ROI

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,9,3)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!